# QXmlStreamReader: Put readNext() at the start or at the end of the loop?

Tags: c++, qt

When reading Xml data with Qt's QXmlStreamReader:

Should readNext() be put at the beginning or at the end of the while(!reader.atEnd()) loop? I've run across many examples that put it at the beginning, but also quite a few that put it at the end.

```
QXmlStreamReader reader;
while(!reader.atEnd())
{
    // <- Put reader.readNext() here?

    QXmlStreamAttributes currentAttributes = reader.attributes();
    // Do something with the attributes
    // ...

    // <- Or put reader.readNext() here?
}
```

My gut says it should be at the start of the loop (to er... read the next xml token, populate attributes() with new data etc.) but I'm not 100% certain (due to the quite a few examples that put readNext() at the end of the loop). Putting it at the end probably would also give me an off-by-one error (atEnd() becomes true with the last readNext(), leaving the last token unprocessed), correct?

Comment: If you put `readNext()` call at the end, what should the reader point to at the beginning of the loop body?

Comment: Good question. I have no idea. As I said, I think it belongs at the beginning, but since quite a few examples put it at the end instead I'm slightly uncertain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand how the class works and what each function does. As a demonstration let's consider the following simple example:

```
QXmlStreamReader reader("<info name=\"Foo\"/>");
while (!reader.atEnd()) {
  //reader.readNext();
  auto currentToken = reader.tokenType();
  qDebug() << currentToken;
  reader.readNext();
}
```

If we run it and print out the values of current token (XML) on each iteration we will get the following sequences:

- *StartDocument, StartElement, EndElement, EndDocument* (`readNext()` call is at the beginning),
- *NoToken, StartDocument, StartElement, EndElement* (`readNext()` call is at the end)

As you can see, if `readNext()` is at the beginning of the loop you can process more elements, including both document's begin and end elements too. Thus the early call of `QXmlStreamReader::readNext()` in such loops is better.